# how to disable word highlighting in Intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

some words are automatically highlighted in intellij how can I disable them,words which have  been highlighted are in use,and it only gets highlighted when they are in use by some other piece of code.How can i disable this?
[in the pic there are some words which are highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en6qz.png)

Answer (score -1):

Activating automatic highlighting of usages

Open the Settings dialog box (File | Settings for Windows and Linux or IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences for macOS), and click General under the Editor node.
On the General page that opens, select the Highlight usages of element at caret check box in the Highlight on Caret Movement area.

Or you can select highlighted text and press Ctrl+Shift+F7(Windows or Linux).